# Preimage of two-dimensional function

Tags: functions

We have the function $f:(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_2)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},|\cdot |)$ with \begin{equation*}f(x,y)=\begin{cases}y-x & y\geq x^2 \\ 0 & y<x^2\end{cases}\end{equation*}

How could we draw the preimage $f^{-1}((1,\infty))$ ? Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we want the pre-image of $(1,\infty)$, we can ignore all regions where the function is equal to $0$. That is, focus on $y \ge x^2$. In particular, we have $f(x,y) = 1 \iff y - x = 1 \iff y = x + 1$. Hence, $f(x,y) > 1 \iff y > x + 1$ and $y \ge x^2$.

At this point, we could stop here and say that you can draw the graphs of $y = x + 1$ and $y = x^2$, and shade the regions that are above both lines (including only the line of the second graph).

To be even more explicit, notice that $x^2 = x + 1 \Rightarrow x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. A quick test shows that $x^2 > x + 1$ for $x < \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ or $x > \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, and $x^2 < x + 1$ for $\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} < x < \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Hence, 
$$f^{-1}((1,\infty)) = \{(x,y) \mid y \ge x^2 \text{ and } x < \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} \text{ or } x > \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\} \cup \{(x,y) \mid y > x + 1 \text{ and } \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} \le x \le \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\}$$

Comment: @Mirko Good point! Thanks for pointing that out, it's fixed now.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: Since at the lower part th eline $y=x+1$ is not included, $f^{-1}((1,\infty))$ is an open set, isn't it?

Comment: @MaryStar It's neither open nor closed. It contains some of its boundary points along $y = x^2$, but none of the ones along $y = x + 1$.

Comment: Ahh ok! I got it! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @MaryStar No problem :)

Comment: One last qusestion... To check if $f$ has maximum or minimum we have to define the gradient, or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76613/discussion-between-alkakadri-and-mary-star).

Answer (score 5):

Sice $0\notin (1,\infty)$, you can focus on the first part and intersect the appropriate half space with that region there.

Comment: I haven't really understood that. Could you explain it further to me?